# How to return a JSON in a trigger function in PostgreSQL?

Tags: postgresql, triggers

I need that when inserting data into a table, a trigger function returns a JSON. But, from what I saw, a trigger function can only return a trigger. What alternatives are there for what I want to do?

```
-- Trigger Function

CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_save_gps_data()

RETURNS json
LANGUAGE 'plpgsql' 
AS 
$$

DECLARE "gpsData" json;

BEGIN

-- PERFORM fn_return_gps_data();
SELECT json_agg(row_to_json(gps)) FROM tbl_admon_gps_data gps INTO "gpsData";

RETURN "gpsData";

END;
$$;

------------------------------------------------------------------------------

-- Trigger that executes the previous Function

CREATE TRIGGER trg_save_gps_data AFTER INSERT ON tbl_admon_gps_data

FOR EACH ROW

EXECUTE PROCEDURE fn_save_gps_data();
```

Comment: The only way this is going to work is if you insert the json into a log/audit table.  From here [plpgsql trigger](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/plpgsql-trigger.html) see *Example 43.4. A PL/pgSQL Trigger Function for Auditing* for the basics.

Comment: The result of a trigger function can't be used directly (and is meaningless in an AFTER trigger). What exactly are you trying to do with the returned JSON value?

Answer (score 0):

The value returned by an AFTER trigger is ignored.  The trigger is only useful for its side effects.

Comment: Very well, thanks...